# set call limitation for some service

Tags: spring

i am working on a spring boot project and i want ti set limitation for some service to call.for example i want in 1 minute,5 request send to this endpoint.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/allJobsByChartCode/{chartCode}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Page<?>> getAllOCMJobsByChartCode(@PathVariable("chartCode") String chartCode, @RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size, @RequestParam(required = false, name = "orderby") String orderby, @RequestParam(required = false, name = "direction") String direction) {

        Page<OCMJobsDTO> gridData = ocmJobsService.getAllOCmJobsByChartCode(chartCode, PageRequest.of(page, size), orderby, direction);
        if (gridData.isEmpty()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(gridData, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Comment: YOu can use zuul. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-zuul-rate-limit

Comment: thanks,but in our project we can not use zuul

Comment: You want to implement on your own or use 3rd party lib ?

Comment: yes we can not zuul for some resons